# Azure Container Registry as a general purpose repository?

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

Can we use Azure Container registry as a general purpose artifactory repository like VSTS Package Manager or Artifactory? If so, what are the common gotchas/pitfalls of doing so? Why is it (not) advisable?

Comment: Do you mean storing none container artefacts in there? or artefacts that are stored in containers?

Comment: No, you cannot. Azure Container Registry: "Simplify container development by easily storing and managing container images for Azure deployments in a central registry."

Comment: thanks for replying. yes, i meant non container artifacts. Can you please confirm that ACR only supports docker containers, can it support other containers like rkt?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Container Register is a managed Docker registry service based on
>   the open-source Docker Registry 2.0. Create and maintain Azure
>   container registries to store and manage your private Docker container
>   images.

It seems that Azure Container Register cannot be used as a general purpose Artifactory repository. You can get more details from the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-intro).

Answer (score 0):

ACR is focused on containers. That said, we are adding Helm Repository Support, which itself are just blobs. While we're not ready to take on generic artifacts as a first class experience, you can push images that derive FROM scratch. 
Steve

Comment: Helm Repositories are now supported (https://aka.ms/acr/helm-repos) ACR also supports the OCI format, so there are many possibilities. We are working with the Azure Artifacts team to provide more seamless integrations between Artifacts, ACR and Helm Repositories.